# Errors in android code

Tags: android

This is the first time I am trying to do android programming. I had been trying hours to use the first example of the code at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm to try to use the camera in my phone.

I modify the exact same file in src/MainActivity.java, res/layout/activity_main.xml, res/values/strings.xml, and AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio. But I am getting the following error. I tried to google it but not really sure why is this happening and it is driving me nuts.

> Error:(29, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with
> value '@drawable/abc').
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

May I ask why am I getting the error? I would also need some help to resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you give us the sample and env you are currently using ?

Comment: do you have a drawable resource with name `abc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates you lack a drawable resource file with the name

> abc

Look in your project directory at `app/src/main/res`. Do you have any `drawable` like folder here? If you have, add some image file to it and name the image file `abc`. If not, first create the `drawable` folder.

More data:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html